# Incorrect number of lines in QTextEdit after paste

Tags: qt, pyqt

I have a QTextEdit widget, i'm using it as a simple text editor, to get the number of lines I simply do

```
QTextEdit.document.blockCount()
```

According to the documentation this returns the number of lines in the document.
This works well when I am typing directly into the QTextEdit widget, however if I copy and paste a block of text(multiple lines) from say notepad text file into the widget the line numbering is no longer correct.
I have also tried

```
QTextEdit.document.lineCount()
```

Can anyone suggest how to get the QTextEdit to handle pasting of multiple lines of text, so the line numbering is correct?
Thanks, ps I'm actually using pyqt4,python 2.7 on windows

Comment: The docs are clear: a block ends with a newline. Therefore count the # of newline characters in the text you paste and you will see if the value returned by these two functions is what you need. Perhaps the pasted text contains linefeed instead of newline? If you type several lines of text in notepad, with newline at end of each line (don't use the wrapping mode of notepad), do you still have same issue?

Comment: Are you on windows or linux ?

Comment: For me it works on Windows when using enter to have multiple lines and no word wrap. If you want to counted wrapped lines too, you should edit the question accordingly.